# 属性 DataMemberAttribute の Name を 動的に変更したい

Tags: c#, json

Json形式のオブジェクトをDataContractJsonSerializerを
つかってシリアライズ・デシリアライズしています。

ここで、DataMemberの名前を動的に変更できるクラスを作成できると非常に楽に書けるのですが、いい方法はありますでしょうか？

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass
{
    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string data1{get;set;}
}
```

この中の `Name="name"` の部分をコンストラクタなどで動的に変更したいです

Comment: デシリアライズ時、`DataContractJsonSerializer`がインスタンス生成するため、動的に変更するのはかなり困難です。もう少し目的を提示していただけたら別のアプローチを提案できるかもしれません。

Comment: プロパティ名が異なるだけで同じ構造のJSONが複数あり、個別にクラスを作るのが面倒だから使いまわしたい、ということですか？

Comment: unaristさんの言われる通りです。パラメータの数がとても多いので使い回しができればコードがスッキリなるかと思って質問して見ました。